Why Is my stl Failing to export into cura
This is the Tale of Two models
and it's a noodle scratcher for me. Now it could be cura based issued so don't smite me down if it is. but It works about 30 percent of the time all the time.
I have two models. Both of the  model I've been working on. The finished product is going to be 3d printed.
The first titled Final copy with flourish, which I can export as an .stl file no problem (I mean it shows as having to be scaled up 100000% but, whats a few decimals between friends )
Now the second model titled final copy with flourish scale down  in which I made a few Minor adjustments to the base in attempt to get better sizing for my part, refuses to open on cura.

I have tried cura 5.3 cura 5.6 and cura 5.7.1 same results every time.
Any idea?
this one is the working model

This one is the broken model


By the way, there is a built-in addon called 3D Print Toolbox that allows you to check for potential problems with your mesh. I recommend enabling it in Edit > Preferences > Add-ons. Apparently you have several problems with your mesh. For example when you click Check All and click Intersect Face it will highlight the 985 intersecting faces. These need to be fixed including other all the other issues. Click each button to highlight the corresponding problematic faces. https://i.sstatic.net/A2lOBgl8.png

The answer is simple:
ALWAYS export models from the Object Mode
*with 2nd model you were trying to export it from Edit Mode.

(!)BUT:
before printing - you should fix these problems
(both models have them):
-Separate mesh parts
-Duplicated vertices
-Loose edges
-Interior faces
-Multiface edges
-Edges with non-contiguous normals
-N-Gons

And an additional info which could be helpful for you:
In the export window - ALWAYS set scale to 1000
(it's necessary due Blender and printing software use different units)

